# mysql query optimisation on huge record

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

i'm writing mysql query for checking any existing record in final table, if so then i will update it first and then insert those records which are not present in final table. issue here is using join its taking more time to execute and since using this in aws lambda its timing out means taking more than 15 mins. i'm not using any index here since i couldn't because we have cusomters who uses the unique constraint on different columns.

```
select count(Staging.EmployeeId)
from Staging 
inner join Final on Staging.EmployeeId = Final.EmployeeId 
where Staging.status='V' 
and Staging.StagingId >= 66518110  
and Staging.StagingId <= 66761690 
and Staging.EmployeeId is not null 
and Staging.EmployeeId <> '' ;
```

I'm looking in range of 250k records at once and no luck using above query. could anyone suggest how to speed up above query. I cannot use index, so looking for other option to optimize above query. thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: You can indeed create the indexes you need. Ordinary, non-UNIQUE, non PRIMARY KEY indexes do not affect the operation of UNIQUE constraints in any way whatsoever, except that indexes impose a bit of overhead on INSERT and UPDATE operations.

Answer (score 2):

Creating indexes to support the search conditions and the join conditions would be the most common and the most effective way to optimize this query.

But you said you can't use indexes. This seems like an inadvisable limitation, but so be it.

Your options are therefore:

1. Allocate more RAM to the InnoDB buffer pool and pre-cache your table data pages, so your table-scans at least occur in RAM and do not have to wait for disk I/O.
2. Upgrade your server to one with faster CPUs.
3. Delete data until your table-scans take less time.

I mean no disrespect, but frankly, your question is like asking how to start a fire with wet newspaper.

Comment: i’m using aurora rds from aws so i can only bump up the instance size. currently using rd5.xlarge instance

Answer (score 0):

"unique constraint on different columns" -- this does not necessarily prohibit adding indexes.  You *must* have some indexes, whether they are `UNIQUE` or not.

```
Staging:  INDEX(status, StagingId, EmployeeId)
Final:  INDEX(EmployeeId)
```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

If any of those columns is the `PRIMARY KEY`, then my advice may not be correct.

Are the tables 1:1?  If not, are the 1:many, and which table is the "one"?

Comment: staging id from staging table is primary key. problem here is we have to add columns at times when a mew customer comes in. so for each customer, they have few different columns. so adding indexes on their columns will slow down the inserts. i tried with temp tables also but that doesn’t work

Comment: So, your real problem is how to allow for the new columns.  I can think of two approaches to _that_.  One involves JSON; the other involves 'parallel tables'.

Comment: could you elaborate on that json and parallel tables? How to achieve those concepts?